# ORA-38101: Invalid column in the INSERT VALUES Clause:

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So i'm in the middle of testing the accuracy of my normalized data by creating a tool to de-normalize the data for comparison. While doing this i was looking into learning new techniques for this tool over what i normally would do(which was using cursors and looping through an insert/update) So i came across two items i wanted to try which were bulk collections and the merge statement. My problem is i'm having some trouble finding the best way to utilize the bulk collection.

**EDIT:**

Okay so i found my problem/solution when it came to the bulk collection. It was in fact the way i was fetching it. Instead of using the forall statement i changed it to a for and added a loop underneath it. Which lead to the discoveries of more bugs. The way i was trying to call the values stored in the indx was being done wrong so i've rectified that. Now the only problem i seem to be having is with the error noted in the title. In my merge for some reason the first value i try to use in the insert throws the following error:

> PL/SQL: ORA-38101: Invalid column in the INSERT VALUES Clause: "TMI"."MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID"
>   ORA-06550: line 92, column 7:

So what i would like to know now is why exactly i'm getting this error. I understand the concept that my insert value is invalid. but i do not fully understand why this is so.

This is the merge statement in question:

```
MERGE INTO TEST_MACHINE_INTERVAL TMI
      USING (SELECT * FROM TEST_MACHINE_INTERVAL) OTMI
      ON (TMI.MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID = OTMI.MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID)
      WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET  TMI.MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID = OTMI.MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID, TMI.START_DATE_TIME = OTMI.START_DATE_TIME,
                    TMI.INTERVAL_DURATION = OTMI.INTERVAL_DURATION,  TMI.CALC_END_TIME = OTMI.CALC_END_TIME, 
                    TMI.MACHINE_NAME = OTMI.MACHINE_NAME, TMI.SITE_NAME = OTMI.SITE_NAME, 
                    TMI.OPERATOR_INSTANCE = OTMI.OPERATOR_INSTANCE, TMI.OPERATOR_INSTANCE2 = OTMI.OPERATOR_INSTANCE2,
                    TMI.OPERATOR_INSTANCE3 = OTMI.OPERATOR_INSTANCE3, TMI.SHIFT_NAME = OTMI.SHIFT_NAME,
                    TMI.INTERVAL_CATEGORY = OTMI.INTERVAL_CATEGORY, TMI.NTP_CATEGORY_NAME = OTMI.NTP_CATEGORY_NAME,
                    TMI.MACHINE_MODE = OTMI.MACHINE_MODE, TMI.JOB_LOAD_STATE_NAME = OTMI.JOB_LOAD_STATE_NAME,
                    TMI.RAW_SOURCE_MSG_TYPE = OTMI.RAW_SOURCE_MSG_TYPE  
       WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (TMI.MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID, TMI.START_DATE_TIME, TMI.INTERVAL_DURATION, TMI.CALC_END_TIME, 
                TMI.MACHINE_NAME, TMI.SITE_NAME, TMI.OPERATOR_INSTANCE, TMI.OPERATOR_INSTANCE2,
                TMI.OPERATOR_INSTANCE3, TMI.SHIFT_NAME, TMI.INTERVAL_CATEGORY, TMI.NTP_CATEGORY_NAME,
                TMI.MACHINE_MODE, TMI.JOB_LOAD_STATE_NAME, TMI.RAW_SOURCE_MSG_TYPE )
        VALUES (MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID, START_DATE_TIME, INTERVAL_DURATION, CALC_END_TIME, 
                MACHINE_NAME, SITE_NAME, OPERATOR_INSTANCE, OPERATOR_INSTANCE2, OPERATOR_INSTANCE3,
                SHIFT_NAME, INTERVAL_CATEGORY, NTP_CATEGORY_NAME, MACHINE_MODE,
                JOB_LOAD_STATE_NAME, RAW_SOURCE_MSG_TYPE);
```

below is the full version of my newly modified code:

```
-- Denormaliztion of machine_interval Table.
-- Is used to take all intervals from interval_table and convert it from 
-- foreign keys to corresponding names.
DECLARE

START_DATE_TIME TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE;
CALC_END_TIME TIMESTAMP(6) WITH TIME ZONE;
MACHINE_NAME VARCHAR2(256);
SITE_NAME VARCHAR2(256);
OPERATOR_INSTANCE VARCHAR2(256);
OPERATOR_INSTANCE2 VARCHAR2(256);
OPERATOR_INSTANCE3 VARCHAR2(256);
SHIFT_NAME VARCHAR2(256);
INTERVAL_CATEGORY VARCHAR2(256);
NPT_CATEGORY_NAME VARCHAR2(256);
MACHINE_MODE VARCHAR2(256);
JOB_LOAD_STATE_NAME VARCHAR2(256);
RAW_SOURCE_MSG_TYPE VARCHAR2(256);
INTERVAL_DURATION NUMBER;
MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID NUMBER;

--step one: Get all the intervals and store them into a cursor
CURSOR INTERVAL_CUR IS 
SELECT * 
FROM MACHINE_INTERVAL 
ORDER BY START_DATE_TIME ASC;

TYPE TOTAL_MACHINE_INTERVALS IS
TABLE OF interval_cur%rowtype
INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

MACHINE_INTERVAL_ROW TOTAL_MACHINE_INTERVALS;

BEGIN 
--step two: Make sure Test_Machine_interval is empty.
  DELETE FROM TEST_MACHINE_INTERVAL;

  OPEN INTERVAL_CUR;
  LOOP
    FETCH INTERVAL_CUR BULK COLLECT INTO MACHINE_INTERVAL_ROW LIMIT 100;
--step three: Loop through all the intervals. 
    FOR INDX IN 1..MACHINE_INTERVAL_ROW.COUNT 
    LOOP
--step four: Gather all datavalues needed to populate test_machine_interval. 

      MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID := MACHINE_INTERVAL_ROW(indx).MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID;
      START_DATE_TIME := MACHINE_INTERVAL_ROW(indx).START_DATE_TIME;
      CALC_END_TIME := MACHINE_INTERVAL_ROW(indx).CALC_END_TIME;
      INTERVAL_DURATION := MACHINE_INTERVAL_ROW(indx).INTERVAL_DURATION;
      INTERVAL_CATEGORY := MACHINE_INTERVAL_ROW(indx).INTERVAL_CATEGORY;
      RAW_SOURCE_MSG_TYPE := MACHINE_INTERVAL_ROW(indx).RAW_SOURCE_MSG_TYPE;

      SELECT M.MACHINE_NAME INTO MACHINE_NAME 
      FROM MACHINE M  
      WHERE MACHINE_ID = MACHINE_INTERVAL_ROW(indx).MACHINE_ID; 

      SELECT S.SITE_NAME INTO SITE_NAME 
      FROM SITE S  
      LEFT OUTER JOIN MACHINE M ON M.SITE_ID = S.SITE_ID 
      WHERE M.MACHINE_ID = MACHINE_INTERVAL_ROW(indx).MACHINE_ID;  

      SELECT O.OPERATOR_NAME INTO OPERATOR_INSTANCE 
      FROM OPERATOR_INSTANCE OI  
      LEFT OUTER JOIN OPERATOR O ON OI.OPERATOR_ID = O.OPERATOR_ID
      WHERE OI.OPERATOR_INSTANCE_ID = MACHINE_INTERVAL_ROW(indx).OPERATOR_INSTANCE_ID; 

      SELECT O.OPERATOR_NAME INTO OPERATOR_INSTANCE2 
      FROM OPERATOR_INSTANCE OI  
      LEFT OUTER JOIN OPERATOR O ON OI.OPERATOR_ID = O.OPERATOR_ID
      WHERE OI.OPERATOR_INSTANCE_ID = MACHINE_INTERVAL_ROW(indx).OPERATOR_INSTANCE_ID_2; 

      SELECT O.OPERATOR_NAME INTO OPERATOR_INSTANCE3 
      FROM OPERATOR_INSTANCE OI  
      LEFT OUTER JOIN OPERATOR O ON OI.OPERATOR_ID = O.OPERATOR_ID
      WHERE OI.OPERATOR_INSTANCE_ID = MACHINE_INTERVAL_ROW(indx).OPERATOR_INSTANCE_ID_3; 

      SELECT NPT_CATEGORY_NAME INTO NPT_CATEGORY_NAME 
      FROM NPT_CATEGORY 
      WHERE NPT_CATEGORY_ID = MACHINE_INTERVAL_ROW(indx).NPT_CATEGORY_ID;

      SELECT S.SHIFT_NAME INTO SHIFT_NAME
      FROM SHIFTS S  
      LEFT OUTER JOIN SHIFT_TBL STBL ON S.SHIFT_ID = STBL.SHIFT_NAME_FK 
      WHERE STBL.SHIFT_ID_PK = MACHINE_INTERVAL_ROW(indx).SHIFT_ID; 

      SELECT MACHINE_MODE_NAME INTO MACHINE_MODE 
      FROM MACHINE_MODE MM 
      WHERE MM.MACHINE_MODE_ID = MACHINE_INTERVAL_ROW(indx).MACHINE_MODE_ID;

      SELECT JLS.JOB_LOAD_STATE_NAME INTO JOB_LOAD_STATE_NAME 
      FROM JOB_LOAD_STATE JLS 
      WHERE JLS.JOB_LOAD_STATE_ID = MACHINE_INTERVAL_ROW(indx).JOB_LOAD_STATE_ID;

    --step five: merge record into test_machine_interval.
      MERGE INTO TEST_MACHINE_INTERVAL TMI
      USING (SELECT * FROM TEST_MACHINE_INTERVAL) OTMI
      ON (TMI.MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID = OTMI.MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID)
      WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE SET  TMI.MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID = OTMI.MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID, TMI.START_DATE_TIME = OTMI.START_DATE_TIME,
                    TMI.INTERVAL_DURATION = OTMI.INTERVAL_DURATION,  TMI.CALC_END_TIME = OTMI.CALC_END_TIME, 
                    TMI.MACHINE_NAME = OTMI.MACHINE_NAME, TMI.SITE_NAME = OTMI.SITE_NAME, 
                    TMI.OPERATOR_INSTANCE = OTMI.OPERATOR_INSTANCE, TMI.OPERATOR_INSTANCE2 = OTMI.OPERATOR_INSTANCE2,
                    TMI.OPERATOR_INSTANCE3 = OTMI.OPERATOR_INSTANCE3, TMI.SHIFT_NAME = OTMI.SHIFT_NAME,
                    TMI.INTERVAL_CATEGORY = OTMI.INTERVAL_CATEGORY, TMI.NTP_CATEGORY_NAME = OTMI.NTP_CATEGORY_NAME,
                    TMI.MACHINE_MODE = OTMI.MACHINE_MODE, TMI.JOB_LOAD_STATE_NAME = OTMI.JOB_LOAD_STATE_NAME,
                    TMI.RAW_SOURCE_MSG_TYPE = OTMI.RAW_SOURCE_MSG_TYPE  
       WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT (TMI.MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID, TMI.START_DATE_TIME, TMI.INTERVAL_DURATION, TMI.CALC_END_TIME, 
                TMI.MACHINE_NAME, TMI.SITE_NAME, TMI.OPERATOR_INSTANCE, TMI.OPERATOR_INSTANCE2,
                TMI.OPERATOR_INSTANCE3, TMI.SHIFT_NAME, TMI.INTERVAL_CATEGORY, TMI.NTP_CATEGORY_NAME,
                TMI.MACHINE_MODE, TMI.JOB_LOAD_STATE_NAME, TMI.RAW_SOURCE_MSG_TYPE )
        VALUES (MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID, START_DATE_TIME, INTERVAL_DURATION, CALC_END_TIME, 
                MACHINE_NAME, SITE_NAME, OPERATOR_INSTANCE, OPERATOR_INSTANCE2, OPERATOR_INSTANCE3,
                SHIFT_NAME, INTERVAL_CATEGORY, NTP_CATEGORY_NAME, MACHINE_MODE,
                JOB_LOAD_STATE_NAME, RAW_SOURCE_MSG_TYPE);

    /*
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO TEST_MACHINE_INTERVAL
                                           (MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID, START_DATE_TIME, INTERVAL_DURATION, CALC_END_TIME, 
                                            MACHINE_NAME, SITE_NAME, OPERATOR_INSTANCE, OPERATOR_INSTANCE2,
                                            OPERATOR_INSTANCE3, SHIFT_NAME, INTERVAL_CATEGORY, NTP_CATEGORY_NAME,
                                            MACHINE_MODE,JOB_LOAD_STATE_NAME,RAW_SOURCE_MSG_TYPE )
                                     VALUES(:1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6, :7, :8, :9, :10, :11, :12, :13, :14, :15)' 
                                     USING  MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID, START_DATE_TIME, INTERVAL_DURATION,
                                            CALC_END_TIME, MACHINE_NAME, SITE_NAME, 
                                            OPERATOR_INSTANCE, OPERATOR_INSTANCE2, OPERATOR_INSTANCE3,
                                            SHIFT_NAME, INTERVAL_CATEGORY, NTP_CATEGORY_NAME,
                                            MACHINE_MODE,JOB_LOAD_STATE_NAME,RAW_SOURCE_MSG_TYPE;
     */
    END LOOP;
  EXIT WHEN MACHINE_INTERVAL_ROW.COUNT = 0; 
END LOOP;
END;
```

I'm 75% sure that my problem lies in how i'm trying to fetch the bulk collection as displayed in the code above. So my question is: How exactly should i be fetching the value from a bulk collection to utilize with the merging of data?

And suggestions or comments are greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you use `FORALL`, what needs to follow is a single SQL statement that you will pass the entire collection to.  If you simply want to iterate over the elements in the collection, you'd use a `FOR` loop.
- The syntax for referring to the n-th element of a collection is `collection_name(index).column_name`.

So, if you want to iterate over the elements in the collection one by one, you'd want something like

```
FOR indx IN MACHINE_INTERVAL_ROW.FIRST..MACHINE_INTERVAL_ROW.COUNT 
LOOP
  MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID := machine_interval_row(indx).MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID;
  START_DATE_TIME     := machine_interval_row(indx).START_DATE_TIME;

  <<more code>>
END LOOP;
```

If you're going to refactor your code, though, I'm not sure what benefit you get from having a local variable `MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID` rather than just using `machine_interval_row(indx).MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID`.  I'm also not sure why you're executing half a dozen separate `SELECT` statements each of which return a single row rather than writing one `SELECT` statement that joins together all these tables and populates whatever local variables you want.

Your `MERGE` is also going to be problematic-- it doesn't make sense for both the source and the destination of a `MERGE` to be the same table-- I would expect you to get an error that Oracle couldn't generate a stable set of rows if it tried to execute that statement.  You could change the source of your query to be a query against `DUAL` that selected all the local variables you've populated, I guess, i.e.

```
  MERGE INTO TEST_MACHINE_INTERVAL TMI
  USING (SELECT machine_interval_row(indx).MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID,
                machine_interval_row(indx).START_DATE_TIME
           FROM dual) OTMI
  ON (TMI.MACHIN_INTERVAL_ID = OTMI.MACHINE_INTERVAL_ID)
```

If `TEST_MACHINE_INTERVAL` is going to start off empty, though, it sounds like you'd be better off not using a `MERGE`, not using a `BULK COLLECT` and just writing an `INSERT ... SELECT` that pulled all the data you want to pull.  Something like

```
INSERT INTO test_machine_interval( machine_interval_id,
                                   start_date_time,
                                   <<more columns>> )
  SELECT machine_interval_id,
         last_value(start_date_time) over (partition by machine_interval_id
                                               order by start_date_time asc
                                           rows between unbounded preceding 
                                                    and unbounded following ) last_start_date_time,
         <<more columns>>
    FROM machine_interval
```

Comment: Well generating a select statement and then inserting the results was the original version of this util. I was using the bulk collect/merge as a way to learn how to use them in a practical exercise, but after reading your response and looking back at the example i was going off of i see now that they were using 2 tables in the merge. Since they were using similar table names i must have missed that i guess.